# Diff dpkg files with local copies

Tags: diff, dpkg

Is there a way of diffing the dpkg files with the one that are actually installed? Or barring that a way to find ones that have been modified?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you're actually trying to do?

Comment: Find files that have been locally modified different then the packages version. I.e. if someone modified /usr/bin/rename it would show up

Comment: Ah. Unpack the deb, then do a diff between files?

Answer (score 1):

Google search brings up this - http://code.google.com/p/dpkg-diffs/

Granted it isn't in Debian and probably not Ubuntu either, but it is just a single file script. Usage is simply:

```
dpkg-diffs package.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also [debsums](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/debsums.1.html): "check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages."

Comment: I thought about this but some of the packages don't have .md5sums file